# Nightmare.js FOR loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, nightmare

I scraped some data in array (JSON), and I need to make autofill in loop with nightmare, for all entries... 
I don't know how to make for loop inside nightmare instance.

var nightmare = Nightmare({show: true});
nightmare

```
.wait(5000)
.goto('http://www.example.com')
.wait('#USER')
.type('#USER', 'xyxyxy')
.wait('#PASSWORD')
.type('#PASSWORD', 'xyxyxyxy')
.click('#Submit')


.wait('#mySidenav > accordion > accordion-group:nth-child(2) > div > div.panel-collapse.collapse > div > div > accordion > accordion-group:nth-child(1) > div > div.panel-collapse.collapse > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > ul > li > a')
.click('#mySidenav > accordion > accordion-group:nth-child(2) > div > div.panel-collapse.collapse > div > div > accordion > accordion-group:nth-child(1) > div > div.panel-collapse.collapse > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > ul > li > a')



//I want for loop start here
.wait('#ctl00_ctl00_SiteMasterContent_NavigationBar1_rgNew_rbNewAvailableLoad_Text')
.click('#ctl00_ctl00_SiteMasterContent_NavigationBar1_rgNew_rbNewAvailableLoad_Text')

.wait(5000)
.wait('#SiteMasterContent_PageContent_ctl00_ctl00_SiteMasterContent_PageContent_chkBrokerablePanel > span > label') UNCHECK
.click('#SiteMasterContent_PageContent_ctl00_ctl00_SiteMasterContent_PageContent_chkBrokerablePanel > span > label')
.wait(2000 ) //wait refreshing fields
.type('#SiteMasterContent_PageContent_txtContactNumber','XXX XXX XXX') 
.click('#NEXT')

// for loop end

.end()
```

There is way to put all nightmare inside loop, but i need only one part to loop... Any ideas how to do that? Thanks...

Comment: Did you trying googling? There are several discussions. Vo library looks like a good option https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/708#issuecomment-258025473

Comment: I feel so stupid now.. Believe me I was googling it for a few days, and I was on this link few times before, and I can't believe I overlooked this specific post... Thank you man!